# publish() in SwingWorker method - error

Tags: java, netbeans, methods, swingworker

I am using a `SwingWorker` class and within the `doInBackground()` method defined as `protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception`, I make a call to the publish method.  This is working fine.  At another spot, I call another method defined as `private boolean myMethod() throws Exception.`  Within this method, I make a call to `publish()`.  I get the following error on this method call from NetBeans which I do not understand:

[image: method error]

I must need to change my `myMthod()` declaration, but I don't know what is missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Swingworker publish method in another class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135228/using-swingworker-publish-method-in-another-class)

Comment: Is there a limit (1) to number of SwingWorker.publish() invocations allowed?

Answer (score 0):

I had to place myMethod() into the SwingWorker class.  All is well.  Very new to SwingWorker.