# I need a simple way to call the java's swingworker publish() method from another class

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, swingworker

The below code is working fine. The only thing that I need is be able to publish() results to the Swingworker from inside Bot() class?

I have searched all over the web to no avail. This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135228/using-swingworker-publish-) did not work for me.

```
JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Bot test = new Bot();
        SwingWorker<Void, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                test.run();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void process(List<String> chunks) {
                for (String s : chunks) {
                    textAreaMain.setText(s);
                }
            }

        };
        worker.execute();
    }
});

btnStart.setBounds(305, 179, 95, 25);
panel_1.add(btnStart);
```

method-in-another-class

//Bot Class has the

```
class Bot {
    void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            publish("Some message");
        }
    }
}
```

With example, how do I write my Bot() class to get what I need?

Comment: Please put in the effort to format your code so that it is easier to read.

Comment: Use an interface that allows `Bot` to call some interested party when it needs something done.  Have the `SwingWorker` register as an interested party and listen for updates - basically an [observer pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm)

Comment: The important point here is to stop thinking in terms of "the `Bot` needs to talk with the `SwingWorker`" and start thinking in terms of "How could interested parties get notified of changes made by `Bot`"

Comment: Any example please?

Answer (score 4):

I would give the Bot class's test method a parameter that accepts a single parameter String function, a callback, and call back through this method.

But really any callback would do, but the Java 8 function references would work perfectly.

e.g.,

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FooJPanel extends JPanel {
    private JButton btn = new JButton("Button");
    private JTextArea textAreaMain = new JTextArea(20, 20);

    public FooJPanel() {
        textAreaMain.setFocusable(false);
        add(new JScrollPane(textAreaMain));
        add(btn);

        btn.addActionListener(e -> {
            final Bot bot = new Bot();
            SwingWorker<Void, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    bot.run(this::publish); // thanks Vince Emigh
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void process(List<String> chunks) {
                    for (String s : chunks) {
                        textAreaMain.append(s + "\n");
                    }
                }

            };
            worker.execute();
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new FooJPanel());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}
```

```
class Bot {

    public void run(Consumer<String> c) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            c.accept("String #" + i);
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But **any** callback or listener construction would work, such as a PropertyChangeListener. As long as you keep coupling low and cohesion high, you should do well.

Comment: @JohnCollins: for example, but *any* callback would work, and that is exactly what you need, a callback of some sort. A PropertyChangeListener or some listener interface could fit the bill.

Comment: Should be able to shorten the example a bit with `bot.run(this::publish);`

Comment: @VinceEmigh: indeed -- Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the `SwingWorker` as a parameter to the `Bot` class and create a method in the `SwingWorker` that calls publish:

```
class Bot {

    Task task;
    public Bot(Task task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    void run() {
        task.publish2("Me");
    }
}

class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

    }

    void publish2(String str) {
        publish(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: This 1) increases coupling to a high degree, and 2) passes view/controller classes into the model (the bot) where it doesn't belong. I do not recommend this.

Comment: The `SwingWorker` is calling the `Bot` and the `Bot` is calling the `SwingWorker`. The coupling is inevitable. Also, the `Bot` seems like a controller class to me in this problem.

Comment: In your case the Bot has to have knowledge of the other class that it is dealing with, and in fact is restricted to working only with `Task extends SwingWorker<Void, String>` objects.